# Drastic changes in tenure process and requirements during evaluation

Tags: united-states, tenure-track, legal-issues, contract

I am an assistant prof. on a tenure-track in the US, in an institution that was heavily oriented toward teaching when I was hired, but that is gradually gearing toward more intensive research activities.

When I was hired, the faculty in my field were hosted by a department primarily devoted to a different field: think of a Math. department hosting a group of Philosophy teachers interested in Logic.
We since transitioned to our own School, and the guidelines and expectations to obtain tenure were re-written from scratch, and considerably inflated (think going from "*2 papers in good journal per years and some undergraduate students*" to "*10 papers in conferences per year and $1,000,000 grants on a regular basis*").

1. Is there any basis to request that I should be granted or denied tenure based on the guideline of the Department that originally hired me (knowing that those guidelines are not a good fit in my field),
2. Is this actually legal, to change the expectations so close to the deadline (I am suppose to go up for tenure next year, and the new guideline was released only a couple of months ago).

My boss seems to act as if, *naturally*, I should have followed those guidelines all along, since they believe that they are "standard" in our field (they may or may not be, I am not qualified to judge).

*To clarify: I understand that there may or may not be legal courses that need to be taken, but I am more interested in understanding if this is customary among, or forced upon, faculty in academia in the US.*

**EDIT** Hmm, some views and votes, but no answer… Should I try https://law.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: Nasty situation. Bait-and-switch. My sympathies.

Comment: I think it's clear what happened.  Someone wanted to make it easy to deny tenure to any assistant professors in your school, so they wrote the guidelines accordingly.  If you are the only one that these guidelines apply to, you should start looking for a new job.

Comment: Sadly, I'd have to second @AnonymousPhysicist's comment. Even if you're not quite the only one who's caught in this, a "structural reorganization" is often used as an excuse to break prior promises/agreements. Don't count on being treated fairly. It may not be personally directed at you, but that doesn't mean that you won't be caught in the mess. Scant consolation. Is there any senior person in the "new" department who can tell you what the "real" new rules are (as opposed to what's "official")?

Comment: @paulgarrett There was one other assistant prof. lined up to get up for tenure before me, and he got it _before_ the guideline was released, so he was assessed based on … noting, or just the "bare minimum" from the University. According to that person, they would have not make it with the new requirements, and don't expect that I will make it. A good number of assistant prof. were hired _after_ me, but they knew this new guideline was coming, and have more time to prepare for it. I am unfortunately pretty much the only one in this situation.

Comment: Sometimes the faculty handbook states that if there is not a criteria in place then the criteria is determined by the metrics of the last person to have been granted tenure in the unit. Worth reading every clause very carefully.

Comment: Are there regular pre-tenure reviews?  If you get annual reviews, and they all say you are on track, it makes it harder (not impossible) for them to justify denying you tenure on the basis of performance.

Answer (score 1):

This is, first and foremost, a question for your faculty handbook. I would assume that, yes, there is a provision to request being evaluated under the prior guidelines. However, the degree to which this will help you is likely dependent on the degree of specificity and objectivity in the prior guidelines.

After checking with the handbook, you likely need to start having some conversations with the personnel committee chair, the department chair, and perhaps higher level reps who have experience with tenure and promotion. Some of the key aspects will likely be making sure the old guidelines are sent to external evaluators and are reviewed at any votes internally. This is easier to do if an advocate makes sure (tactfully) that everyone remembers in advance of any critical step that you are to be evaluated under the old guidelines.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your sharing your interesting point of view. Unfortunately, this restructuring came with a big "power grab" from our now boss, who never delegate anything to anybody. I'm afraid whether I get tenure or not will be their last word. While they are somehow re-assuring when discussing, they are unequivoqual in writing, spelling out quite clearly that I will not obtain tenure. And I believe their stance will be impossible to bypass. But, as you wrote, this is something to look for in the faculty handbook, and I will study it some more.

Comment: It is useful to note that if the criteria are objective then school-level committee can overrule the department. It is unusual but could be something you could marshall resources around , particularly if you unambiguously meet the earlier criteria. Is your P&T committee chair the same as your department chair? Usually there is a voting process and nothing is decided by one person.

Comment: Most universities are very careful to follow the faculty handbook to the letter because not doing so is grounds for a lawsuit. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Legal questions aside, getting tenure is ultimately about satisfying the expectations of a department, a college, and the university -- and these expectations are not always explicit, but inherent in the opinions of people, and *they change over time*. There is little you can do about this: If a department has recently hired a lot of excellent people, then expectations go up and someone who ten years ago might have gotten tenure, may no longer get tenure simply because *in the opinion of those who vote on the case*, the candidate does not stack up against the recent crop of candidates any more.

This is simply inherent to the game. It is no different to an Olympic athlete who now comes in fifth because the competitors have worked harder during training, even though eight years ago he might have gotten a gold. You can't sue the Olympic committee that you should get a medal anyway. Similarly, departments generally make decisions about candidates *relative to others in similar positions*, and unless a faculty manual explicitly spells out that "X publications, Y dollars of grant funding, and Z teaching awards will get you tenure", you don't really have much of a basis for a lawsuit. Of course, faculty manuals -- at least at good universities -- do not actually spell things out this way, and that's on purpose. Rather, manuals say that a candidate needs to show "excellence in their research area": A term that is both *relative* and *subject to interpretation*, both on purpose.

Whether all of this is something you can challenge in court is a question I'm not prepared to answer. But I *am* prepared to say that you will always be measured relative to your peers, and that that is universally true, not just when it comes time for tenure, but also for pay raises, promotions, etc., both within and outside academia.